# How would I get the name of a member of Spotify using their User ID on Spotipy

Tags: python, spotify, spotipy

I am trying to get the current listed name for a user on Spotify, by their User ID. I am using the spotipy library as my API. Does anyone know of any viable methods to get the name of the user by their User ID. I am running Python 3.11

I have looked through all of the user commands that I can see, however nothing visible is there for me to find this. I have probably just overlooked something but thought it was best to ask.

Comment: I don't understand that you mentioned `the current listed name for a user on Spotify`.  Or `the name of a member` in title.  Can you explain what is listed name? If you add screen capture of example, It help to understand your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want `user(user)`. It's in the documentation [spotipy docs](https://spotipy.readthedocs.io/en/2.22.1/?highlight=current_user#spotipy.client.Spotify.user)

where the user argument is the ID you reference.